# Show the reponse with Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an Entry which is used to ask a riddle. I put certain conditions there. My guess is displayed correctly and I can enter answers but the success message does not appear.
The objective was to limit to 3 response attempts and to display a Dysplayalert in the event of an error. Otherwise, there was a Label which displayed the rest of the scenario.
What would be my mistake?

My XAML :

```
<!--Row 08-->
        <Entry x:Name="Enigme01"
               IsVisible="false"
               Placeholder="Ecrire la réponse."
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
               IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
               ReturnType="Send"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Grid.Row="8"/>
```

My XAML.CS

```
 public void Entry_Completed (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reponseEnigme01 = Enigme01.Text;
        string soluce1 = "chaussette";
        int CompteurEnigme = 0;

        while ((soluce1 != reponseEnigme01) & (CompteurEnigme < 3))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Info:", "Mauvaise réponse", "ok");
            CompteurEnigme++;

            if (CompteurEnigme >= 3)
            {
                Reponse04.TextColor = Color.DarkRed;
                Reponse04.Text = "A force de cogiter pour trouver la réponse, vous ne voyez pas les gardes arriver. Ils vous attrapent et finisser ainsi votre carrière d'aventurier dans une geôle.";
            }
        } 
        if (reponseEnigme01 == soluce1)
        {
            Reponse04.Text = "Bravo, vous avez donné la bonne réponse et la porte s'ouvre.";
            Reponse04.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: first, you `Entry_Completed` handler is not actually wired up in your XAML so it will never fire (unless you are setting it up in code not shown).  2nd, your `while` loop is pointless - the user will never be able to enter in another response while the loop is running.

Comment: `Entry` has a `Completed` event, you need to attach your event handler to it

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the solution, I added: Completed and it works, I just have to solve the details of the while.